# How do I force the column alias to be of specific data type?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an alias in the select like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE ....
    WHEN 1 THEN somefield * -10
    WHEN 0 THEN somefield * 10
    END as myAlias
FROM
    ....
```

the problem is that at the first record that mysql seeks, it marks the "myAlias" as UNSIGNED
but in some next record the same alias produces a SIGNED integer, then I have the error:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in....
```

so, how to tell mysql before it does any operation that "myAlias" is a SIGNED INTEGER?

thanks!

edit:

I've tried

```
SELECT
    CAST(CASE ....
    WHEN 1 THEN somefield * -10
    WHEN 0 THEN somefield * 10
    END AS SIGNED) as myAlias
FROM
    ....
```

without success!

Comment: What is the type of `somefield`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the field in your table is declared as `UNSIGNED INTEGER`. In that case, you have to type cast the field in the `THEN` clause of the `CASE` expression. Below example illustrates a sample.

#### Create and insert script:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
     numberfield INTEGER UNSIGNED
   , bitfield BIT
);

INSERT INTO mytable (numberfield, bitfield) VALUES
  (134, 1),
  (673, 0),
  (855, 1),
  (133, 0),
  (778, 1),
  (234, 0);
```

#### Type casting the field in THEN clause: [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3bb/3)

```
SELECT
    CASE bitfield
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(numberfield AS SIGNED) * -10
        WHEN 0 THEN CAST(numberfield AS SIGNED) * 10
    END as myAlias
FROM mytable
```

*Output*:

```
MYALIAS
-------
-1340
6730
-8550
1330
-7780
2340
```

#### Alternative way to write the above query: [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3bb/8)

```
SELECT
    CAST(numberfield AS SIGNED) * 
    (
        CASE bitfield
            WHEN 1 THEN -10
            WHEN 0 THEN 10
        END
    ) as myAlias
FROM mytable
```

*Output*:

```
MYALIAS
-------
-1340
6730
-8550
1330
-7780
2340
```

#### Without type casting the field: [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3bb/4)

```
SELECT
    CASE bitfield
      WHEN 1 THEN numberfield * -10
      WHEN 0 THEN numberfield * 10
    END as myAlias
FROM mytable
```

*Error*:

> Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db_5b3bb`.`mytable`.`numberfield` * -(10))': SELECT CASE bitfield WHEN 1 THEN numberfield * -10 WHEN 0 THEN numberfield * 10 END as myAlias FROM mytable

Comment: thanks! really helpful, now the SQL is a lot more concise!! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "cast()" function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

EX:
`select * from mytable where myfield=cast(somefield as UNSIGNED INTEGER)`

Comment: Suggestion: Then try the cast where you *use* myAlias